# HBase table splitting

Tags: hbase

I am trying to create an HBase table with pre-splitting. Where I am having a row key as combination of bucket number, schema and pkid. I am able to do pre-splitting the table with the ranges as `{'00000000000000000', '10000000000000000', '20000000000000000',.....'f0000000000000000'}`. Is there a way that I can do this automatically using auto splitting policy. Which will help me in including schema name also to splitting like `'0MD5(schema1)000000000...', '1MD5(schema1)000000000...', ...,'fMD5(schema1)000000000...', '0MD5(schema2)000000000...',.....`

The above splitting will help me a defining a better design. And here we can't define number of schemas, right now we are creating the table for 10 schemas, and in future for some more schemas. We need to insert data into this table. So I am looking for a better design in the splitting policy.

I have also looked for `KeyPrefixRegionSplitPolicy`, it looks like this will help, and I am not very sure on this.

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyPrefixRegionSplitPolicy can meet you needs  
here is some code example may help

```
    HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
    HTable hTable = new HTable(conf, "test");
    HTableDescriptor htd = hTable.getTableDescriptor();
    HTableDescriptor newHtd = new HTableDescriptor(htd);
    newHtd.setValue(HTableDescriptor.SPLIT_POLICY,     KeyPrefixRegionSplitPolicy.class.getName());
    newHtd.setValue("prefix_split_key_policy.prefix_length", "1");
    admin.disableTable("test");
    admin.modifyTable(Bytes.toBytes("test"), newHtd);
    admin.enableTable("test");
```

now the table 'test' will auto split region with partition by the rowkey prefix 1

Comment: Yes, this information helped me to proceed with KeyPrefixRegionPolicy. But I tired with some examples, when I insert multiple rows with the values for my row key id as (123, 234, 456, test1234). I expected it will create 4 regions in hdfs. But I couldnt see 4 regions, only one region I can see. Am I doing any thing wrong here.

Comment: a region only do split when the region size reach "hbase.hregion.max.filesize",if you do not set in your table descriptor,the default is 10G since hbase0.94+

Comment: I have configured the region size as 256 MB while doing this testing, but I have imported the data more than that size, I will cross verify on this. But this is a very good concept in HBase.

Comment: Pre split your Hbase table then data will get spread,, hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.RegionSplitter <Table Name> HexStringSplit -c <number of splits> -f <coulmn family >